# Parameterize Schema in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have multiple object and some of them go to one schema "NewObjects" and the other go to "OldObjects"  I want to be able to make what the NewObjects Schema is configurable from config file.  Is there a way?  Here is what I have.

```
namespace IDJC.Domain
{


    [Table("Agency", Schema = "NewObjects")]
    public class Agency
    {
        public int AgencyId { get; set; }
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, through [fluent api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591617.aspx#schema). Check the part: Mapping an Entity Type to a Specific Table in the Database:

For example, if you create a setting in your project (through Properties->Settings) name *MySchemaName*, you will be able to access it in your DbContext derived class. So when you override OnModelCreating you will be able to do something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Agency>()  
    .ToTable("Agency", Properties.Settings.Default.MySchemaName);
```

Comment: :) no worries, hope it helps.